# highcharts: fire animation when visible instead of on page load

Tags: animation, highcharts

i have a page separated out into sections that are accessed via anchors.
is there a way to have the highcharts animation fire when its particular section becomes visible instead of on page load?

http://jsfiddle.net/YFMSb/2/ (the chart is under 'skills', so would like its initial animation to occur when that section of the page is brought up. does not need to re-animate during subsequent visits to/through the section)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            spacingTop: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },


        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
               return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'clean',
            data: [10],
        }, {
            name: 'eat',
            data: [10]
        }, {
            name: 'sleep',
            data: [40]
        }, {
            name: 'work',
            data: [30]
        }, {
            name: 'play',
            data: [10]
        }]

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when its particular section becomes visible"?

Comment: when 'skills' is clicked in the nav, the anchor tag readjusts the page to show the #skills div where the graph is located, and it is at this point i would like the animation to fire. since the site will be one long page, if it fires on page load the animation won't be visible since the the graph will be located too far down the page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attach a scroll event listener to the window that detects when you get close to the `skills` section. When you create the chart, remove the scroll listener to ensure that the chart is only created once. This will also help with performance: no reason to listen to an event that we aren't going to respond to anymore.

This approach also works if the user clicks the `skills` link at the top.

You want to be careful with the scroll event as it can be a real performance bottleneck. I took the [approach](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) suggested by John Resig to check the scroll position at regular intervals.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YFMSb/17/)**

```
$(function () {
    var $window = $(window),
        didScroll = false,
        skillsTop = $('#skills').offset().top - 40; //the point at which we will create the chart

    $window.on('scroll', function () {
        //detected a scroll event, you want to minimize the code here because this event can be thrown A LOT!
        didScroll = true;
    });

    //check every 250ms if user has scrolled to the skills section
    setInterval(function () {
        if (didScroll) {
            didScroll = false;
            if ($window.scrollTop() >= skillsTop) {
                createChart();
            }
        }
    }, 250);

    function createChart() {
        $window.off('scroll'); //remove listener that will create chart, this ensures the chart will be created only once

        $('#container').highcharts({
            //chart configuration here
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: wasn't me, i used your solution and was quite appreciative of the explanation provided. voted it up so at least now its back to even. and thank you, btw.

Answer (score 2):

I'm supposing with "section becomes visible" you meant a scroll event.

This is the most basic code to make it work:

```
var target = $('#container');
var targetHeight = target.get(0).offsetTop;
var printed = false;
var printChart = function(){ 
    if(printed) return;
    printed = true;
    target.highcharts({
        chart: type: 'bar',
        /* all chart code */
    });
};
$('[href="#skills"]').on('click', printChart);
$(window).on('scroll',function(e){
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(st > targetHeight) printChart();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YFMSb/12/

Comment: yes sorry if i was unclear. this is close but the graph is continuing to reprint itself with page scroll. once the skills div is accessed and the initial animation occurs, i'd like the graph to stay loaded.

Comment: I edited so it prints only once and works for every anchor. Did you really not thought about a simple if condition check? And please dont vote down, I'm trying to help you here.

Comment: though some sort of conditional check seemed logical i unfortunately do not yet have enough js knowledge to know how to implement it... hence why i posted here. and i was not the one who down voted you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the chart on click of 'skills'. jsfiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/YFMSb/6/

```
$("#your skills link").click(function(){
         createChart();  
    });
```

createChart() basically defines your chart.

Comment: this works for when 'skills' is clicked, but also needs to work if the section is scrolled to manually. however, the animation only needs to happen once. after that first time the user enters the #skills div (whether by click or scroll), the graph should stay loaded.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YFMSb/6/ 

You need listeners to listen scroll and little bit of click counting to make that work.