# Load Highchart animation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have developed several highcharts and I would like to start the animation when the user scrolls down and the graph container is visible.

Here is a fiddle of my work: http://jsfiddle.net/LWmn5/

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            options3d: {
                enabled: false,
                alpha: 0
            }
        },

        colors: ['#081969', '#0e2569', '#1e3b81', '#284893', '#30509b'],
        title: {
            text: ''
        },tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: 140,
                depth: 45
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Delivered amount',
            data: [
                ['43.6%', 43.6],
                ['22.5%', 22.5],
                ['17.9%', 17.9],
                ['5.1%', 5.1],
                ['10.8%', 10.8]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

$(function () { 
    $('#container3').highcharts({

                                legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 25,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 20,
                beta: 25,
                depth: 70
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 45,
                 colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
            colors: [
                '#081969',
                'grey',
                '#30509b'
            ],
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['21.56Mbps Melita', '19.47Mbps EU Average', '7.93Mbps GO'],
            labels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            opposite: true,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
        },
        series: [{
            name: '',
            data: [4, 3, 2]
        }]
    });
});
```

Appreciate your great help guys!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [highcharts: fire animation when visible instead of on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364088/highcharts-fire-animation-when-visible-instead-of-on-page-load)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of these plugin:

http://scrollrevealjs.org/

http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html

Comment: Managed to get the effect with scrollrevealjs

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar request before in the past, I found this helped:

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/4457022-start-the-animation-when-the-chart-scrolls-in-to-v

Comment: I did that attempt and it worked fine on JSFiddle but for some reason when I integrated the whole code as a Wordpress page template it didn't work

Comment: may be you missed something or plugins conflict occurs sometimes

Comment: If you have issues like this then quite often something useful will show up in the debug console. Either way, looks like your problem has been solved using one of the other plugins available :)