# onscroll show hide div

Tags: jquery, onscroll

I had a problem to show hide div on scroll actually I have used a code and it is working on scroll top and show my div but now when I scroll up, the div should hide now so how can I do?

Is there any code `.scrolldown`

here is my code which i used and working fine

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 800) {
        $('.scroll-navigation').show();
    } else {
        $('.top-navigation').hide();
    }

});
```

now I just want to hide this div ('.scroll-navigation') when I scroll up.

Comment: check this answer, hope it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513312/load-highchart-animation-on-scroll/23513406#23513406

Comment: Can you just add `$('.scroll-navigation').hide();` after 
        `$('.top-navigation').hide();`

Comment: The question rambles. Is your question "How do I hide this div whenever the user scrolls up?" or is it "How do I hide this div when the user scrolls up and scrollTop>800?" or other?

Answer (score 0):

In same your code, using y for detremind when you need to show and hide, scrollTop(); is enough to do your work, no method or function was name scrolldown(); but you can do it dependance of y

now how ..

console.log(y) .. do this event when you scrolling and log in you console in browser debug you will see 
0 
100
200
300
..ets

now set condition dependance of these value ..ify == 100 show else y == 500 hide ..

good luck