# How to improve loading time of page with multiple highcharts graphs?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, highcharts

I have a page containing multiple Highcharts graph. For instance: http://baptiste-wicht.com/perfs/index.html

I think that the loading time is a bit slow (I'm on Firefox). The page blocks and then everything display at once, it is not really practical.

I have a div for each graph and each graph is loaded with jquery $ function (once the page is ready).

Is there a way to make the different code blocks run in parallel or simply improve highcharts loading time ?

Even if the page still take long to finish rendering, it would be great if the rendering were done smoothly.

Thanks

Comment: You could postpone rendering/creating of not visible charts until user scrolls to them. You might find useful similar topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513312/load-highchart-animation-on-scroll , http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/4457022-start-the-animation-when-the-chart-scrolls-in-to-v

Comment: We use `waypoints.js` - https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints